# What is the different between using `\captionof{table}{ABC}` and `\caption{ABC}`?

Tags: tables, captions

What is the different between using `\captionof{table}{ABC}` and `\caption{ABC}`?

It seemed the same output.

Comment: The first can be used outside a `float` e.g. outside a `table`, whereas the second can be used only inside a `float` such as `table`. The first is not a default LaTeX command, whereas the second is.

Comment: @cfr. Thanks. I not sure what is the meaning of `float` in latex, is that mean `floating around in a page`? you can write the answer too, i can select it

Answer (score 5):

- `\caption`

  - can be used only inside a `float` and
  - is provided by the LaTeX format itself.
- `\captionof`

  - can be used outside a `float` (and is intended for use outside `float`s, though it will work inside them, too, and
  - is not provided by the LaTeX format, so must be defined by the user, typically by loading one of the packages `captof` or `caption`.

A `float` is an environment whose contents LaTeX should place in the 'best' position it can, according to its placement algorithm. This means that a `float` can move later relative to text which follows it in the source.

By default, the only two `float` environments are `table` and `figure`.

`\captionof` is designed for tables and figures which need captions but which must not be moved later in the document. In these cases, it is better not to use `table` or `figure` at all, but to just insert the `tabular` or image or whatever.
However, you can't then use `\caption`. To solve this problem, `\captionof` was created. It can be used to give captions to things which shouldn't move.

Comment: thanks. How about in term of output? Is both the output the same?

Comment: @aan The output should be the same unless you do something special. That's the point of `\captionof`.